# Read only recordset "local" update

Tags: ms-access, dao, recordset

I have DAO recordset that is generated with pass-through query to postgresql stored function. I use it to fill out combobox in my form. What I need is additional item in combobox with "AllItems" description. But the recordset is read-only (that's normal in this case). So I cannot just add new row to it. Can I do any kind of in memory recordset clone, copy or anything like that to make addition possible? I don't want to update recordsource. And I don't want to hardcode this option in to the pgsql function as well.

```
Public Sub fillCboAssortmentType()
    
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    If (lngViewContext = acMyItems) Then
            Set rs = getAssortmentTypesByDAO(TempVars!loggedUser)
    Else (lngViewContext = acAllItems) Then
        Set rs = getAssortmentTypesByDAO
    End If
        
' It wont work, because the rs is RO
    With rs
        .AddNew
        !type_id = 0
        !type_name = "***AllItems***"
    End With
        
' It wont work neither, because cboTypeFilter rowsource is Table/Query
    Set Me.cboTypeFilter.Recordset = rs
    Me.cboTypeFilter.AddItem "0;***AllItems***"
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?
TY All.

Comment: You can use UNION ALL to add AllItems, or read the recordset into a value list string, where you add AllItems (and change the combobox row source type to Value List). Both not really what you are asking for... but easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for a "In Memory" Recordset. Let's assume you have a table which looks like this

[image]

Then the following code will read the values from the table and copy it to a in memory recordset and add a new value but only in memory

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

    Sub inMemory()
    
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        With rs.Fields
            .Append "val", adVarChar, 64
        End With
    
        Dim sourceRs As DAO.Recordset
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set sourceRs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl")
        
        Dim i As Long
        rs.Open
        Do Until sourceRs.EOF
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields(0).Value = sourceRs.Fields(0).Value
            rs.Update
            sourceRs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(0).Value = "Cancel"
        rs.Update
        
        ' let's print the list just for testing
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: And how is that recordset used as RowSource for combobox?

Comment: What do you mean? I would use `AddItem`?

Comment: So loop through recordset and build Value List string for combobox RowSource? Would UNION query as RowSource as suggested by @Andre be simpler approach?

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion. You are free to post another solution.

Comment: Union All is the way to go for me. In this particular example I stuck and needed your kick guys to move forward. As in memory table is a great solution, for me it was better and easier to do Union All. Thank You.